# How to insert data in mysql table through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I can create table structure by PHP. But unable to insert data.

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
<?php

$tbl[]="
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$table_prefix."admin_user (
  `admin_id` int(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,  
  `user_lang` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lost_password_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `session_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_access` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
";

/*insert user account*/

     $params_user=array( 
    'username'=>$data['username'],
    'password'=>md5($data['password']),
    'date_created'=>date('c'),
    'ip_address'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'user_access'=>$user_all_access
  );
  echo "<p class=\"uk-icon-chevron-right\"> Inserting user ...</p>";      
  $truncate="TRUNCATE TABLE ".$table_prefix."admin_user";   
  $db->raw($truncate);
  $db->create( $table_prefix."admin_user", $params_user); 
  echo "<div> [done]</div>";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is insert? and Why are you truncating the table?

Comment: I can just see creation of the table

Comment: sorry,but I am new to this stuff. I don't know much about mysql. I just pasted the data from file. Can you explain where the error was?

Comment: There is no error as such. But there is no insert statement in your code, so no records are inserted into the database if you execute the code in the question.

Comment: where is your insert query? you have just created the table & truncate the table. show us the insert query

Comment: Ok I understood that this code is missing the insert statement, I will check it with the developer. Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual line of code that tells the SQL-Server to put in any kind of data.
To put in data, the SQL query should look like

```
"INSERT INTO ".$table_prefix."admin_user [...]"
```

Also: Even if you had some content in this table, the line

```
$truncate="TRUNCATE TABLE ".$table_prefix."admin_user";
```

is deleting everything inside. So every single row that might have been writen into this table is gone afterwards.